# Why is Unity (Compiz) consuming more and more RAM?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, ram

About 3 to 4 hours after turning on my PC, compiz 'memory usage' rose from **300MB** up to **1.5GB**!
What is happening? What is wrong?

Here is the screen-shot from system monitor:

[image: system monitor]

Comment: It seems like a bug, mine doesn't move beyond 150MBs no matter what. do you have any of the extra plugins enabled (those not installed by default , i mean, that can be found in synaptic. i think they are called "compiz-plugins-unsupported" or something like that)

If not, you should probably send a bug report

Comment: I think it was because of "window preview" plugin. it's on `compiz-plugins-extra` package. when I disable it, launch-bar and panel went black! and when I run `unity --replace` memory usage decrease to about 50MB

Comment: Warning: the previous command should be `unity --replace &` when executed from the console.

Comment: In my case it was `unity-scope-clementine`. [Uninstall it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213694) and unity is sane now.

Comment: Would love to add my screenshot, 13.4 GiB used by unity-panel-service on my machine with 16 GB RAM... Fail

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), probably in multiple places. It should be fixed by Compiz developers. It has been [filed as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/720446). Please mark yourself as being affected

Comment: I think so, I thought it was because of **extra plugins** but it happened again, and by restarting unity memory usage coma back to 25MB

Comment: 2014 and this memory leak still exists. At least its a well know bug caused by the "indicator-multiload". Just remove it from your system. https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/+bug/779717

Answer (score 7):

I was running into this, and just running "unity --replace &" was enough to drop it from 1.5GB down to about 110MB. I'm guessing Unity is telling compiz to create buffers that Unity is failing to tell compiz to clean up.
At least I have a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Report this as a bug to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/720446